# Are the parentheses necessary in this Haskell code

Tags: haskell

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show) 
data Line = Line Point Point deriving (Show)    
onLine :: Line -> Point -> Bool
onLine (Line (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) (Point x y) = True
```

Is there a way not to use so many brackets ?

Comment: You can remove braces around the `Show` deriving clause. There is nothing more you can do; after all, how do you separate argument patterns from each other without braces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend a tool called [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm) for identifying places where you can simplify your code.

In your code /as written/, you're not using the values `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `x` or `y`, so you could just write:

```
onLine _ _ = True
```

However, I assume that's just a stub, and in reality you will do something with the variables. In general, if you really need to reference all those variables, then you need to write it the way you have done. However, maybe you're using a helper function that only needs the entire line value. Then you could write something like:

```
onLine l p = blah blah blah 
   -- use slope l and yIntercept l to figure out if p is on the line

slope :: Line -> Float
slope (Line (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

yIntercept :: Line -> Float
yIntercept (Line (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = blah blah blah
```

Alternatively, you can just use accessor functions to extract the x and y co-ordinates from points and lines, but in this case it will probably make your code messier.

Also, in Haskell I believe it's generally more efficient to use `Double` rather than `Float`.

Comment: Thank you for the last hint ! I also found that by using float i can not use negative numbers such as -1. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can use negative numbers, it's just that sometimes you need to enclose them in parentheses. See the section "An arithmetic quirk: writing negative numbers" in chapter 1 of Real World Haskell (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can sometimes avoid brackets with record notation, sometimes with `$`, sometimes with infix functions, and sometimes they're OK if not excessive.

Let's use record notation for points, which get heavy access for the coordinates, but we'll leave `Line` alone.

```
data Point = Point {x::Double,y::Double} deriving (Show) 
data Line = Line Point Point deriving (Show)
```

This defines `x :: Point -> Double` and `y :: Point -> Double`.

There's no such thing as equality for floating points, but I'll go for roughly right:

```
accuracy = 0.000000000001

is :: Double -> Double -> Bool
is x y = abs (x - y) < accuracy
```

I can use this as `` x point1 `is` x point2 `` neatly avoiding the bracketed `is (x point1) (x point2)`

When your data structure is not so heavily nested with pattern matching, a few brackets are easy to read:

```
gradient :: Line -> Double
gradient (Line one two) = (y two - y one) / (x two - x one)
```

But we can go one level deeper without using excessive brackets because of the functions `x` and `y`.

```
asFunction :: Line -> (Double -> Double)  -- ( ) for clarity, not necessity
asFunction l@(Line point _) = \xx -> gradient l * (xx - x point) + y point
```

Notice I've used `l@` to introduce an alias for `(Line point _)` to save typing on the right.

Now we can use the infix function trick to get rid of a few more brackets:

```
onLine :: Line -> Point -> Bool
onLine l p =  l `asFunction` x p `is` y p
```

On the right hand side, you can use `$` to get rid of brackets, but you can't use it on the left in pattern matching because it's a function `f $ x = f x`. For example

```
  this  (that  (the other thing  (something other)))
= this $ that $ the other thing $ something other
= this . that . the other thing $ something other
```

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout. That is indeed what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the line and point apart within the function by defining accessors, but there is no way to do the pattern matching without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting rid of the parentheses is to do the pattern matching in a number of case expressions:

```
onLine l p = case l of
    Line p1 p2 -> case p1 of
        Point x1 y1 -> case p2 of
            Point x2 y2 -> case p of
                Point x y -> True -- you can use x1,y1,x2,y2,x and y here
```

This is close to what the compiler 'translates' the patternmatches to, but of course this is not much of an improvement!

However, there are a number of ways of writing this expression that *also* translate to the same cascaded pattern matching; here's one:

```
onLine l p = let
    Line (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) = l
    Point x y = p
    in True
```

and here's another:

```
onLine l p = True where
    Line (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) = l
    Point x y = p
```

The last one is pretty nice and readable, in my opinion, but the other suggestions are much better, since they'll lead to a better structured program!

(There's some stuff about irrefutable patterns that I'm glossing over, and this only works for single-constructor datatypes)